# dependency resolution in nodejs with prerelease versions

Tags: node.js, npm, dependency-management

I'm using nodejs and i'm trying to set some prerelease version in my package.json

My prerelease version is like:

```
"version": "0.10.0-rc1"
...
"version": "0.10.0-rc9"
"version": "0.10.0-rc10"
```

and at package.json of other app is like:

```
"dependencies": {
    "my_app": "~0.10.0",
...
```

until v0.10.0-rc9 the dependency resolution was working fine, but now the version v0.10.0-rc10 is not being caught.

Does anyone have any idea to solve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
0.10.0-rc.10
```

I haven't tried it on npm but using the semver package (the actual one used by npm) I have replicated your problem and found that this format solves it.

It's my understanding that npm will always sort a pre-release statement as a string, unless it can be seen as an integer in it's entirety. (A statement is separated by a dot)

That would make sense considering the problem and solution. When comparing integers, 10 is greater than 9, but when comparing strings, "9" (or "rc9") will be greater than "10" (or "rc10"), as strings are compared on a per-character base from left to right.